# HTML default date not reflected on view

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am designing a website using AngularJs,Codeigniter and Bootstrap.
I'tried various ways (even inserted hard coded values) to make the date appear on the date field.
But instead it always shows just the format mm/dd/yyyy.
Using the following method I get to see the the value of date input as current date but only in the console.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
     <div class="input-group" style="border-color:#d0a12b;" ng-init="currentPage=1" ng-init="i=1">
           <input type="date"  id="when" ng-init="when=<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"  ng-change="currentPage=1" ng-model="when" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" style="border: 2px solid #d0a12b;opacity:0.8;" placeholder="When">                           
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call the correct way time and date in HTML5.

```
 echo '<time datetime="'.date('c').'">'.date('Y - m - d').'</time>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

This just generates a string of the year/month/day Hour/minute/second in that order. So to use it simply set it as a variable and put it where you need.

e.g.

`$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $date;`

You could optionally do this:

`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

However this is 'unclean' code.